# concurrent SQL statements in different transanctions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, transactions

Reading up the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS2001) of PL-SQL `CREATE TRIGGER` statement in ORACLE, I went through the following bit of information:

> When a trigger fires, tables that the trigger references might be
>   undergoing changes made by SQL statements in other users'
>   transactions. SQL statements running in triggers follow the same rules
>   that standalone SQL statements do.

It basically says the rules that would apply to two conflicting standalone SQL statements (running at the same time) are unchanged when one of the statements is performed from within a trigger.

So we have some "usual" rules about concurrent transactions and, as for these rules, the following two are mentioned:

> Specifically:
>
> Queries in the trigger see the current read-consistent materialized
>   view of referenced tables and any data changed in the same
>   transaction.
>
> Updates in the trigger wait for existing data locks to be released
>   before proceeding.

These two rules look like "obscure" to non-expert users.

What do they mean more precisely?

Comment: Fair set-up for the question, and fair question. However, this is not the right place to get the answer. This site (Stack Overflow) is for specific programming questions. The place to learn about how Oracle handles transactions in a multi-user environment (things like data locks, read-consistent view, etc.) is the Oracle documentation, where they are explained very clearly and with good examples - or any book about Oracle Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Queries in the trigger see the current read-consistent materialized
>   view of referenced tables and any data changed in the same
>   transaction.

This means the data the trigger sees, like if it does a `SELECT` on a different table, represents the state of that table when the statement started running. The trigger does not see rows that have been changed by other sessions that have not been committed yet.

> Updates in the trigger wait for existing data locks to be released
>   before proceeding.

When an Oracle statement modifies a row, the row is locked against other people changing it until that session either commits or rolls back its transaction. So if you do an insert on table A, your trigger does an update on table B, but someone else's session has already done an update on table B *for that same row*, your transaction will wait until they commit or rollback.